# How to verify a request from Slack Events API

Tags: node.js, express, http-post, slack-api

I am using the [validate-slack-request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/validate-slack-request) package to validate my incoming slack requests are from slack. This works fine for Slash commands and Interactive Components (buttons, etc.). However it is not working for the Events API

I noticed that the POST request body has a different format for the Events API. There's no `payload`. But it's not clear to me what slack is giving me to use to verify. Code is below

```
//This WORKS
app.post("/interactiveCommand", async (req, res) => {
  const legit = validateSlackRequest(process.env.SLACK_SIGNING_SECRET, req, false);
  if (!legit) {
    console.log("UNAUTHORIZED ACCESS ", req.headers, req.body);
    return res.status(403).send("Unauthorized");
  }
  await interactiveCommand(...);
  return;
});

//This does NOT WORK
app.post("/slackEvents", parser, json, async (req, res) => {
  const legit = validateSlackRequest(process.env.SLACK_SIGNING_SECRET, req, false);
  if (!legit) {
    console.log("UNAUTHORIZED ACCESS ", req.headers, req.body);
    res.status(403).send("Unauthorized");
  } else {
    try {
      switch (req.body.event.type) {
        case "message":
          await handleMessageEvent(...);
          break;
        case "app_home_opened":
          res.status(200).send();
          await updateUserHomePage(...);
          break;
        default:
          res.status(200).send();
          return;
      }
    } catch(e) {
      console.log("Error with event handling! ", e);
    }
  }
});

const crypto = require('crypto')
const querystring = require('querystring')

// Adhering to RFC 3986
// Inspired from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent
function fixedEncodeURIComponent (str) {
  return str.replace(/[!'()*~]/g, function (c) {
    return '%' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16).toUpperCase()
  })
}

/**
 * Validate incoming Slack request
 *
 * @param {string} slackAppSigningSecret - Slack application signing secret
 * @param {object} httpReq - Express request object
 * @param {boolean} [logging=false] - Enable logging to console
 *
 * @returns {boolean} Result of vlaidation
 */
function validateSlackRequest (slackAppSigningSecret, httpReq, logging) {
  logging = logging || false
  if (typeof logging !== 'boolean') {
    throw new Error('Invalid type for logging. Provided ' + typeof logging + ', expected boolean')
  }
  if (!slackAppSigningSecret || typeof slackAppSigningSecret !== 'string' || slackAppSigningSecret === '') {
    throw new Error('Invalid slack app signing secret')
  }
  const xSlackRequestTimeStamp = httpReq.get('X-Slack-Request-Timestamp')
  const SlackSignature = httpReq.get('X-Slack-Signature')
  const bodyPayload = fixedEncodeURIComponent(querystring.stringify(httpReq.body).replace(/%20/g, '+')) // Fix for #1
  if (!(xSlackRequestTimeStamp && SlackSignature && bodyPayload)) {
    if (logging) { console.log('Missing part in Slack\'s request') }
    return false
  }
  const baseString = 'v0:' + xSlackRequestTimeStamp + ':' + bodyPayload
  const hash = 'v0=' + crypto.createHmac('sha256', slackAppSigningSecret)
    .update(baseString)
    .digest('hex')

  if (logging) {
    console.log('Slack verifcation:\n Request body: ' + bodyPayload + '\n Calculated Hash: ' + hash + '\n Slack-Signature: ' + SlackSignature)
  }
  return (SlackSignature === hash)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I got it to work, it was a little bit of trial and error and I make no promises. Basically, if I was validating an Event rather than a Slash Command or an Interactive Component, I would pass `type="Event"` to the validation function. The only change is how I construct the payload from the incoming request

```
export function validateSlackRequest(
  slackAppSigningSecret,
  httpReq,
  logging,
  type = ""
) {
  logging = logging || false;
  if (typeof logging !== "boolean") {
    throw new Error(
      "Invalid type for logging. Provided " +
        typeof logging +
        ", expected boolean"
    );
  }
  if (
    !slackAppSigningSecret ||
    typeof slackAppSigningSecret !== "string" ||
    slackAppSigningSecret === ""
  ) {
    throw new Error("Invalid slack app signing secret");
  }
  const xSlackRequestTimeStamp = httpReq.get("X-Slack-Request-Timestamp");
  const SlackSignature = httpReq.get("X-Slack-Signature");
  let bodyPayload;
  if (type === "Event") {
    bodyPayload = (httpReq as any).rawBody;
  } else {
    bodyPayload = fixedEncodeURIComponent(
      querystring.stringify(httpReq.body).replace(/%20/g, "+")
    ); // Fix for #1
  }
  if (!(xSlackRequestTimeStamp && SlackSignature && bodyPayload)) {
    if (logging) {
      console.log("Missing part in Slack's request");
    }
    return false;
  }
  const baseString = "v0:" + xSlackRequestTimeStamp + ":" + bodyPayload;
  const hash =
    "v0=" +
    crypto
      .createHmac("sha256", slackAppSigningSecret)
      .update(baseString)
      .digest("hex");

  if (logging) {
    console.log(
      "Slack verification:\nTimestamp: " +
        xSlackRequestTimeStamp +
        "\n Request body: " +
        bodyPayload +
        "\n Calculated Hash: " +
        hash +
        "\n Slack-Signature: " +
        SlackSignature
    );
  }
  return SlackSignature === hash;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I convert text payloads into json with this:

```
IFS=$'\n'
if [ "$REQUEST_METHOD" = "POST" ]; then
 if [ "$CONTENT_LENGTH" -gt 0 ]; then
  cat - > /tmp/file.txt
 fi
fi
cat /tmp/file.txt | sed -e "s/^payload=//g" | perl -pe 's/\%(\w\w)/chr hex $1/ge' > /tmp/file.json
```

Comment: Can you share more about how this would work in a node environment if I didn't want to mess with tmp files?

Comment: Apologies -- I cannot.  My environment is BASH scripts so I can't speak to how/where node collects the POST payload.  But if you can create your own executable shell scripts that can be called from within node, and into which you can feed the POST payload and capture the output, the shell script itself would only need one line:

sed -e "s/^payload=//g" | perl -pe 's/\%(\w\w)/chr hex $1/ge'

Comment: Googling alleges that there is PERL within node so all you really to do is remove the "payload=" at the beginning of the POST data, then convert all the HTML entities into their viewable equivalent.  The JSON is in there - its just been encoded for web viewing (for some reason).

Comment: It looks to me like the Events API body payloads are the same format (json) as all the other payloads we get from Slack. Are you saying the Events API send text payloads? Or is it something to do with the structure of the payload?

Comment: The raw POST body for a block event looks like this:
`payload=%7B%22type%22%3A%22block_actions%22%2C%22user%22%3A%7B%22id`

chopping off the payload= and rendering those hex codes as their actual characters gives this

`{"type":"block_actions","user":{"id`

if you are already seeing the JSON then this is not an issue for you.

Comment: Yep `request.body` is already json format. So perhaps something to do with slack's method of signing event POST requests..