# Verify a request from Slack Events API with C#

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, slack-api

[This example](https://api.slack.com/authentication/verifying-requests-from-slack)  in the Slack documentation uses a form-url-encoded body but the Slack Events Api sends json. I've attempted to implement the pseudo code in the example with the C# crypto namespace. Not able to get a matching signature.

When I inspect the request body in C# it includes escaping for the quote (") characters which I'm pretty sure aren't in the request body when it's hashed on the Slack side. How can I know that my raw version of the request body matches what Slack used to create the hash? Is there something wrong with the way I'm using the HMACSHA256?
Also looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64794287/2679816) but found nothing that I could extrapolate to C#.

```
{
...
    string signingKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Slack:SigningSecret"].ToString();            
    string timestamp = GetHeaderValue(actionContext, "X-Slack-Request-Timestamp");            
    string SlackSignature = GetHeaderValue(actionContext, "X-Slack-Signature");

    var app = HttpContext.Current;
    string requestBody = string.Empty;
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        app.Request.InputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        app.Request.InputStream.CopyTo(stream);
        requestBody = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.ToArray());                
        app.Request.InputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);                
    }  

    string sig_basestring = "v0:" + timestamp + ":" + requestBody;
    var hmac256 = HMACSHA256.Create();
    hmac256.Key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(signingKey);
    var sig_hash = 
    hmac256.ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sig_basestring));

    var computedSignature = "v0=" + ToHex(sig_hash, false);
    bool isValidRequest = SlackSignature.Equals(computedSignature);

    if (!isValidRequest)
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);
    }
...
}

private string ToHex(byte[] bytes, bool upperCase) 
{
    var result = new StringBuilder(bytes.Length * 2)
    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
            result.Append(bytes[i].ToString(upperCase ? "X2" : "x2"));
        return result.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: It looks like Google has the solution https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/slack#understanding_the_code - if you select C# there is a implementation that works

Answer (score 3):

I came across [SlackNet](https://github.com/soxtoby/SlackNet/blob/master/SlackNet.AspNetCore/SlackRequestHandler.cs) and found the solution that works:

```
var encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
using (var hmac = new HMACSHA256(encoding.GetBytes(signingSecret)))
{
    var hash = hmac.ComputeHash(encoding.GetBytes($"v0:{timestamp}:{requestBody}"));
    var hashString = $"v0={BitConverter.ToString(hash).Replace("-", "").ToLower(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)}";
    if (hashString.Equals(SlackSignature)) return continuation();
}
...
```

Comment: Hi Rick. Thanks for providing an answer to your question. I'd like to suggest that you could improve it by putting the salient points about what worked directly in your answer. This would address a couple of things. 1) Linking to a working implementation is good, but an explanation is better. 2) If that linked resource ever goes away, there'll be nothing useful here for future visitors.
Thanks again for helping.

Comment: ja! thanks Dominic - that just occurred to me and I returned to find your comment. Going to edit now... cheers